# AMPL nonquadratic nonlinear constraints with cplex

Tags: optimization, constraints, mathematical-optimization, cplex, ampl

I'm working on an optimization project and I faced a small problem. For my project, I'm using AMPL and CPLEX as a solver. In my code, I have some elements indicated by e1, e2, ..., en. I also have a set which contains tuples within these elements. I must assign a number between 1 and 'n' to each element such that I maximize the distance between every 2 elements in 1 tuple in the moveTuples set (I need to order them but try to keep a distance between elements in the same tuple).

Every element MUST have ONLY 1 assigned number and each number should be given to ONLY 1 element. For this purpose, I wrote the following code:

```
set Elements;
set moveTuples dimen 2;
set Numbers;

var assign {Elements,Numbers} binary; 
var maximizer{moveTuples} integer >= 0; 

maximize obj: sum {(A,B) in moveTuples} maximizer[A,B];

subject to assign1NumberPerElement {i in Element}: sum {c in Numbers} assign[i,c] = 1;
subject to assign1ElementPerNumber {c in Numbers}: sum {i in Element} assign[i,c] = 1;


subject to moveApart {(A,B) in moveTuples}:  abs(sum{i in Numbers}(assign[A,i]*i) - (sum{j  in Numbers}x[B,j]*j)) - maximizer[A,B] = 0  ;

data;

set Elements:= e1 e2 e3;
set Numbers:= 1 2 3;
set moveTuples: e1 e2 e3:= 
(e1, e2);


solve;

display assign;
```

Now the problem is clear and for the previous example, the output must be either:

e1 -> 1

e2 -> 3

e3 -> 2

or

e1 -> 3

e2 -> 1

e3 -> 2

since it is required to only move e1 from e2 using the tuple (e1,e2). When running the previous code, I get the error: ... contains a non-quadratic non-linear constraint (definitely the "moveApart" constraint). Can you please guide me on how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you use the square difference instead of the absolute difference, does it return a solution? I also don't understand why you bother using a constraint, is it impossible to just use "maximize obj: sum {(A,B) in moveTuples} abs(sum{i in Numbers}(assign[A,i]*i) - (sum{j  in Numbers}x[B,j]*j));" (or the corresponding square difference objective function)?

Comment: Thank you sir. Using the suggested objective did not work so I had to modify it a little bit to work. `maximize obj: sum {(A,B) in moveTuples, i in Numbers, j in Numbers: i != j} (assign[B,j]*assign[A,i]*num(i) - assign[A,i]*assign[B,j]*num(j));`. The only problem is assuming the the tuples were (e1,e2),(e3,e4),(e2,e5). Now the objective is 6 and it is correct but the correct sequence must be (e1,e3,e2,e4,e5) so no 2 elements in the same tuple will be following each other and the objective will stay 6. AMPL produces the sequence (e5,e4,e2,e1,e3) ==> obj = 6 but e1 and e2 are consecutive.

Answer (score 0):

The constraint `moveApart` is nonlinear (and non-quadratic) because it contains a call to `abs`. However, since your problem is purely integer, you can solve it with [CPLEX CP Optimizer (ilogcp)](http://ampl.com/resources/logic-and-constraint-programming-extensions/#ilogcp).